# How to launch a Django project from within pycharm without using terminal?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

with other projects I've developed I have been able to hit 'run' to launch my application, and then `shift+F10` from then on.

It seems excessively cumbersome to have to launch the terminal and type `python manage.py runserver` every time I want to test something...

Is there a better way? can I write a python file like ***run.py*** with some script that will launch the app, or some other solution?

Edit:
I worked out to add 'runserver' as an argument to the run config for ***manage.py***.... is there a better way?
I've searched for ages, and all I can find is a thousand tutorials telling me how to start a project, rather than how to launch it more easily.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it' so simple. i've been trying all manner of hacky approaches to make a script, but i finally found 'django server' in the run configurations, complete with a launch browser option.

awesome.